# Boot Errors on fresh Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Installation

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, broadcom

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Mac Mini (late 2012) and am running macOS Catalina (10.15) in dual boot on the same machine. So far it's going pretty well. Since I'm new to Linux, I was wondering if the errors on the start screen are seroius errors that needed to be fixed. On a Googlesearch I found a tip to use the `dmesg` command to view a log file of the boot process in the terminal so I can check for errors and try to fix them.

So I found some errors and since  I want to learn more about Linux and Ubuntu. It would be great to fix them. But since I'm pretty new to all this command line information, I'd appreciate some help.

#1

```
[    0.127991] DMAR: Host address width 36
[    0.127991] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0
[    0.127999] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap c0000020e60262 ecap f0101a
[    0.128003] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed91000 flags: 0x1
[    0.128007] DMAR: dmar1: reg_base_addr fed91000 ver 1:0 cap c9008020660262 ecap f0105a
[    0.128009] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000008b800000 end: 0x0000008f9fffff
[    0.128013] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 0 under DRHD base  0xfed91000 IOMMU 1
[    0.128014] DMAR-IR: HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed91000

[    0.128016] DMAR-IR: [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping** will be disabled

[    0.128021] DMAR-IR: Not enabling interrupt remapping
[    0.128023] DMAR-IR: Failed to enable irq remapping. You are vulnerable to irq-injection attacks.
```

#2

```
[    0.243345] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] (____ptrval____) (20221020/exresop-66)
[    0.243345] ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20221020/dswexec-433)

[    0.243345] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PDC]
[    0.243345] Initialized Arguments for Method [_PDC]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    0.243345]   Arg0:   (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Buffer(12) 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

[    0.243345] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20221020/psparse-529)

[    0.243345] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.243345] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9015C0A54C00 0003A4 (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.243345] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.243345] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9015C0E44A00 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.243345] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.243345] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.243345] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
```

#3

```
[    9.165285] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[    9.165821] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 7 (HT), Revision 1
[    9.165835] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2059, Revision 0, Version 1
[    9.165839] b43-phy0 warning: 5 GHz band is unsupported on this PHY
[    9.171056] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.171099] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.171140] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[    9.171174] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw failed with error -2

[    9.171178] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    9.171187] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    9.171192] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

[    9.171319] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]

[    9.202190] usb 3-2.3.1: current rate 33186 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[    9.210263] usb 3-2.3.2: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x83
[    9.214624] usb 3-2.3.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x4
```

#4

```
[   12.651871] usb 3-2.3.1: current rate 33186 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[   12.677685] usb 3-2.3.1: current rate 33186 is different from the runtime rate 44100

[   12.704014] usb 3-2.3.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x4
```